# How can I make TypeScript error out when I try to access a property on a potentially undefined array?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a variable with the type `SomeObject[] | undefined` and I'm accessing the `.length` property, but TypeScript is not warning me about it being potentially undefined. Here's a screenshot from vscode:

[image: Screenshot from VSCode]

As you can see there is no red squiggly line.

I have tried to reproduce this on the TypeScript playground, but I can't (it always warns me about the property being potentially undefined).

I've enabled `strict`, `strictNullChecks`, `strictFunctionTypes`, `strictPropertyInitialization` and `strictBindCallApply`, but I can't find the option to make TypeScript produce an error here.

Which option do I need to enable to make TypeScript warn me about the property being potentially undefined?

**Edit:** Since somebody added the vscode tag, I should also add that there are no errors or warnings when I run `tsc --noEmit -p .`, so it is not about vscode.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a VSCode issue, if you can't reproduce it on the official playground

Comment: When I run tsc it is not complaining, so it is not just vscode.

Comment: Can you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (both explicit code and tsconfig)

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that when enabling `strictNullChecks` VSCode didn't pick up the config change. I'd try turning it on and restarting VSCode (run the action "Developer: Reload Window")

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. There are two parts to this story.

The reason I started this goose hunt was because of a runtime type error when the `.reports` property was `undefined`. But the problem here was not TypeScript, but rather that I type hinted a response from the server without actually validating that the data had the correct type. So yes, `.reports` was undefined, but the type of `.reports` said it could not be undefined.

But Visual Studio Code is saying the property can be `undefined`? How does it know that and why isn't it warning me when accessing the `.length` property?

It turns out that the vscode type hint is ambiguous. What it's saying is that the *expression* which I'm hovering is `FilteredReport[] | undefined`, which is not the same thing as the *property* having that type (I have to say I really think it looks like they're presenting the property type there though). The property type is actually just `FilteredReport[]`, but because of the optional chaining the expression could evaluate to `FilteredReport[] | undefined`.

I have created an issue for vscode concerning the tooltip: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94348